# Can't add Object to the List. SpringBoot. MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, list, spring-boot

I can't add anything to the list 'games' and I don't understand why. Everything works well with MySQL but I can't save the object into List game with MongoDB. The 'game' is successfully created and saved in the collection. Will appreciate any help.
Thank you!

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "player")
public class Player {
    @Id
    private String playerId;
    private String name;
    private LocalDate registerDate;
    @Transient
    Double rate;

    @JsonIgnore
    @DBRef
    private List<Game> games = new ArrayList<>();

    //{games = new ArrayList<>();}

    public Player(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.registerDate = LocalDate.now();
    }
```

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.DBRef;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Document(collection = "game")
public class Game {
    @Id
    private String gameId;
    private int dice1;
    private int dice2;
    @JsonIgnore
    @DBRef(lazy=true)
    private Player player;
    private boolean win;

}
```

```
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.kuzmina.ganna.s05.t02.n01.DiceGameS05T02N01MySQL.exceptions.HttpException;
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.kuzmina.ganna.s05.t02.n01.DiceGameS05T02N01MySQL.model.domain.Game;
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.kuzmina.ganna.s05.t02.n01.DiceGameS05T02N01MySQL.model.domain.Player;
import cat.itacademy.barcelonactiva.kuzmina.ganna.s05.t02.n01.DiceGameS05T02N01MySQL.model.repository.GameRepository;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;


@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GameServiceImpl implements GameService{

    private final GameRepository gameRepository;
    private final PlayerService playerService;
    private  final PlayGameServiceImpl playGameService;
    @Override
    public Game playGame(String playerId) {
        if(playerService.getAllPlayers().isEmpty()){
            throw new HttpException(HttpStatus.INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE,"There is no registered player");
        }
        Player player = playerService.findPlayerById(playerId);
        if(player==null){
            throw new HttpException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"Player with this id is not found");
        }

        Game gamePlayed = playGameService.play();
        gamePlayed.setPlayer(player);
        player.calculateRate();
        playerService.saveGame(gamePlayed,playerId);
        return gameRepository.save(gamePlayed);
    }
```

Implementation of method play in playGameService:

```
@Override
    public Game play() {
        int dice1 = getRandomNum();
        int  dice2 = getRandomNum();
        return Game.builder().dice1(dice1).dice2(dice2).win(getWin(dice1,dice2)).build();
    }
```

PlayerServiceImpl:

```
    @Override
    public void saveGame(Game game, String playerId){
        Optional<Player> player = playerRepository.findById(playerId);
        player.get().getGames().add(game);
    }
```

Controllers:

```
    @PostMapping("/{id}/games")
    public ResponseEntity<?> playGame(@PathVariable String id) {

        Game gameToSave;
        try {
            gameToSave = gameService.playGame(id);
        } catch (HttpException ex) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getStatus()).body(ex.getMessage());
        }
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(gameToSave);

    }
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not saving player information like using playerRepository.save(). As you did for gameRepository.

```
@Override
    public void saveGame(Game game, String playerId){
        Optional<Player> player = playerRepository.findById(playerId);
        player.get().getGames().add(game);
        playerRepository.save(player); // saving player information with new game data
    }
```